# .Net Service Fabric - An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

For debugging purposes, I have created a new C# console project and I have referenced an existing service in the console project so that i call a async Task method from the service and debug it.  But when i run the Console Project, I am running into issues and exception is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
> occurred in Unknown Module. Additional information: Could not load
> file or assembly 'RingCentralArchiver, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

exception screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please confirm that RingCentralArchiver is a x64 assembly

Comment: @PeterBons
Yes it is x64.   what i did is - on the Console project which i created  i have set to x64 which fixed the issue.  Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Glad that you have fixed your issue. kindly post your fix as an answer so that it will helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

@PeterBons Yes it is x64. what i did is - on the Console project which i created i have set to x64 which fixed the issue.

Thanks for the inputs.